# Properties of Non-Diagonally Dominant Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question

I have a question about properties of matrices which are or are not diagonally dominant.

So I understand that a diagonally dominant Hermitian matrix with non negative diagonal entries is positive semi-definite, and that diagonally dominant implies that the matrix is non-singular.

My questions are: what can we say about a matrix where only one or two rows do not satisfy the diagonal dominance requirement; can we say anything about the data encoded in the matrix or the linear transformation the matrix represents? And is regularizing a matrix to diagonal dominance a good way to ensure invertibility?

Comment: [Gershgorin disc theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) may be helpful.