# non diagonally dominant = singular?

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

There are non-strictly diagonally dominant matrices which are nonsingular [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689668/are-non-strictly-diagonally-dominant-matrices-nonsingular/1912475#1912475)].

However, I found no information or reference to the following question: 
are all non (strictly or not) diagonally dominant matrices also singular?

(The Gershgorin circle theorem does not provide a definite answer on any eigenvalue being zero in this case)

After doing a search I found that something similar (but not quite as general) was asked here before [[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338920/properties-of-non-diagonally-dominant-matrix)], 5 years ago, but received no answer. Maybe someone can answer it now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure that $\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$ is not diagonally dominant.

(Diagonal dominance is a useful sufficient condition for nonsingularity,
but it is not a necessary condition.)